# The number of categories must be greater than one but fewer than five

Tags: database-design, relational-database

I want to create a database application for creating academic examination. The database contains, for the sake of simplicity, 3 tables as follows.

**Problems:**

- ProblemID (int, identity, primary key)
- Problem (nvarchar)
- Solution (nvarchar)

**Categories:**

- CategoryID (int, identity, primary key)
- Category (nvarchar)

**ProblemCategory:**

- CategoryID (int, composite primary key)
- ProblemID (int, composite primary key

Each problem is linked to at least one category and at most 5 categories. My question is how to make sure this constraint is hold in database level?

### Bonus question:

Is the following design recommended as a replacement for the design above?

**Problems:**

- ProblemID (int, identity, primary key)
- Problem (nvarchar)
- Solution (nvarchar)
- CategoryID1 (int, not null)
- CategoryID2 (int, null)
- CategoryID3 (int, null)
- CategoryID4 (int, null)
- CategoryID5 (int, null)

**Categories:**

- CategoryID (int, identity, primary key)
- Category (nvarchar)

Comment: Alternatively, you could do something [along these lines](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23202984/533120).

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: Each problem is linked to at least one Category.

Answer: declare a foreign key constraint on the Problems table.

```
Problems.ProblemID REFERENCES ProblemCategory.ProblemID
```

(Presumably there's also foreign key constraints
 declared on ProblemCategory to reference Problems.ProblemID and Categories.CategoryID.)

Question 2: Each problem is linked to at most 5 Categories.

Answer: declare a constraint on the ProblemCategory table.
        (As Branko points to.)

```
WHERE (SELECT MAX(CatCount)
       FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) AS CatCount
             FROM ProblemCategory
             GROUP BY ProblemID)
      ) <= 5
```

Question 3: Design with up to five Cat ID per Problem record.

Answer: No, that's a terrible idea. (Read any text about normalisation.) Consider:

- How to query for all Problems with Category "Normalisation"?
- How would you prevent the same Cat getting repeated on a given Problem?
- What does it mean for a Problem to have Cat ID3 and ID5 but ID4 IS NULL?

Comment: Would have been a much more respectable answer had you pointed out the _downsides_ of trying to apply your Q1 and Q2 "solutions".  Q1 downside : introduces "circular reference via constraints" and the associated insert sequence problem or put alternatively, inability to do this on any engine that doesn't support deferred constraint checking.  Q2 downside : the nature of the constraint is still that it's a multi-row constraint and (a) most engines don't support this, (b) those that accept it are not likely to enforce it correctly in all cases (c) strongly contraindicated perfomancewise anyway